# Need incremental increasing ticks for y axis, currently ticks are not even increasing by default

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am trying to create a plot with multiple bars in groups where the ticks on the y-axis are increasing, like this example:

[image]

My python program is running as below, based on the following tutorial: https://pythonspot.com/matplotlib-bar-chart (see the example at the bottom)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

print('grabbing data...')

PATH = './thesis_results_processed.txt'
results = open(PATH, 'r')

print('getting started...')

# for each line
for line in results:
    # get the space seperated values on this line
    items = line.split()

    print('making chart for dataset: ' + items[0])

    # bar variables
    num_groups = 4
    bar_width = 0.2 if len(items) == 17 else 0.3
    plt.subplots()
    index = np.arange(num_groups)

    plt.bar(index, items[1:5], bar_width, label='bar 1')

    plt.bar(index + bar_width, items[5:9], bar_width, label='bar 2')

    plt.bar(index + bar_width * 2, items[9:13], bar_width, label='bar 3')

    if len(items) == 17:
        plt.bar(index + bar_width * 3, items[13:17], bar_width, label='bar 4')

    # chart features
    plt.xlabel('group')
    plt.ylabel('speed (milliseconds)')
    plt.title(items[0])
    if len(items) == 17:
        plt.xticks(index + bar_width * 1.5, ('2', '3', '4', '5'))
    else:
        plt.xticks(index + bar_width, ('2', '3', '4', '5'))

    plt.legend()

    # show chart
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
```

However, when I create the plot the results on the y axis are not even increasing. Ideally, I will have evenly spaced ticks on the y-axis increasing logarithmically (i.e. in powers of 10).

As you can see in the result below, the ticks on the graph are not in increasing order and look really bazaar.

[image: plot]

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your are working with strings rather than numbers. The problem is that `matplotlib` (and Python in general) does not know how to sort strings (what is higher: `'-1'` or `'1'`? The first has two chars but its numeric value is lower... but how should Python know this? There is no difference to `'Hello world!'`).

So

- either use a different method to read in data, e.g. with `pandas` as they show in [this](https://www.delftstack.com/howto/python-pandas/how-to-load-data-from-txt-with-pandas/) tutorial, or
- use your way but convert the text of your `line` to numbers: `items = [float(s) for s in line.split()]`